# The Correctness of the "We Don't Track" Statement While Being on a Third-Party Cloud Platform

Tags: user-tracking

When a company says:

> "We don't track", and our application is on a third-party cloud platform.

Is it true to say, their users' data are still trackable. The company might not track at all, however their cloud provider might; and have the ability to do so if they wanted.

Comment: You have used 2 different phrases and seem to be equating them: "we do not track" and "not trackable" - it's all trackable, it just matters what the intent is. What you are looking for is a statement from the company saying what they do to make it possible that the cloud service provider may not track, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to you question but :
The "company" says to you : **"We don't track"** AND the third-party says to the "company" :**"We don't track"**.
You can trust both but never in **"THEY don't track"**